# Summing varibles to a profit varible

Tags: mql4, indicator, metatrader4

UPDATE!!!
So I write the update at the top just so I remember this for later.

I found out why SellProfit shows wrong profit.
It turns out the the summing function trigger the first Selltrigger and dosent display it but still keep that value to the end. This means it gives false results.

[image]

As you can see in the picture we only have one buySquare and no SellSquare 
but the SellProfit comment (up to the left) still shows a sellvalue.
So it count the first selltrigger and the last sellClose as one trade but doesn't display it.

I don't know how to fix this in the code I have now but think I may be able to fix it if I insted look at the text element and try to collect them and sum them that way. It feals like the wrong way to go but all I can think of so far.

---

So.

I'm working on a Indicator that plots buy/sellsignal entry and closeorder for those.
I'm also working on displaying the profit of that order.

it looks like this.

```
double               SquareStartPrice        = 0;
double               SquareEndPrice          = 0;
double               OrderStartPrice         = 0;
double               BuyProfit               = 0;
double               SellProfit              = 0;
double               profit                  = 0;
```

and

```
 if(BuySignal && !BuyOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         }
      if(BuySignalOut && !BuySignalOut_Bool)
        {
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         BuyProfit += (SquareEndPrice-SquareStartPrice);
         //profit = (profit+BuyProfit);
        }
      if(SellSignal && !SellOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
        }
      if(SellSignalOut && ! SellSignalOut_Bool)
        {
         SellProfit += (SquareStartPrice-SquareEndPrice);
         profit = (profit+SellProfit);
        }
```

The problem I have is when summing the the SellProfit. It dosen't ad it up correctly but the BuyProfit works (I think).

it looks something like this.
[image]

Green Square are BuySignal and the number to the left is the profit.
Red Sqyare are the SellSignal and the number to the left is the profit.

BuyProfit = (15.3) + (-4.38) = 10.92
SellProfit = (-1.07)

If we look at the comment thats under the sympol we see that BuyProfit is correct but not SellProfit.

Where do I start locating where the problem is?

And here is the whole code: (don't know if I can attatch the .mq4 file)

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         Test.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
//#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 3
#property indicator_plots   3
//--- plot EmaTrend
#property indicator_label1  "EmaTrend"
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1  clrBlack
#property indicator_style1  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width1  4
//--- plot EmaShort
#property indicator_label2  "EmaShort"
#property indicator_type2   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color2  clrRed
#property indicator_style2  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width2  4
//--- plot Trend
#property indicator_label3  "Trend"
#property indicator_type3   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color3  clrGreen
#property indicator_style3  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width3  4
//--- input parameters
//input int            LookBack= 5000;
input datetime       LookBackTo = D'2020.06.01 00:00:00';
extern double        Static_LotSize=0.01;

extern string        ____Moving_Average____ = " //////////////////// ";
input int            myEmaTrend_Value       = 350;
input int            myEmaShort_Value       = 9;

extern string        ____MACD____ = " //////////////////// ";
//input bool            myMACD_Bool            = true;
input int            myMACD_FAST_EMA        =12;
input int            myMACD_SLOW_EMA        =26;
input int            myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA      =9;

extern string        ____RSI____ = " //////////////////// ";
input int            myRSI_Period           =14;
input int            myRSI_High             =70;
input int            myRSI_Low              =30;

extern string        ____DeMarker____ = " //////////////////// ";
input int            myDeMarker_Period      =14;
input double         myDeMarker_High        =0.70;
input double         myDeMarker_Low         =0.30;

extern string        ____BuySellSignalOut____= " //////////////////// ";
input bool           myEma_Bool             = true;
input bool           myRSI_Bool             = false;
input bool           myDeMarker_Bool        = false;




bool                 BuyOrder_Bool           = false;
bool                 SellOrder_Bool          = false;
bool                 BuySignalOut_Bool       = false;
bool                 SellSignalOut_Bool      = false;

double               SquareStartPrice        = 0;
double               SquareEndPrice          = 0;
double               OrderStartPrice         = 0;
double               BuyProfit               = 0;
double               SellProfit              = 0;
double               profit                  = 0;

int                  objcount=0;
int                  BuySquareCount=0;
int                  SellSquareCount=0;

color                SquareTextColor=clrBlack;
color                InfoTextColor=clrBlack;
int                  ButtonXSize      = 140;
double               pipsmultiplier;

//--- indicator buffers
double         EmaTrendBuffer[];
double         EmaShortBuffer[];
double         TrendBuffer[];
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//--- indicator buffers mapping
   SetIndexBuffer(0,EmaTrendBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,EmaShortBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(2,TrendBuffer);
   deleteObjects();

   if(MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_DIGITS)==3 && MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_DIGITS)==5)
     {
      pipsmultiplier=10;
     }
   else
     {
      pipsmultiplier=1;
     }

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {
//--- initial zero
   int limit = rates_total - prev_calculated;
   ArraySetAsSeries(EmaTrendBuffer, true);
   ArraySetAsSeries(EmaShortBuffer, true);
   ArraySetAsSeries(TrendBuffer, true);
   SetLabelObject("TestPos1","TestPos1",10,40,InfoTextColor);


   int      shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,LookBackTo);
   Comment("BuyProfit = "+calculatePip(BuyProfit)+ "\n" + "SellProfit = "+calculatePip(SellProfit)+ "\n" +"SHIFT = "+shift);

   if(prev_calculated < 1)
     {
      ArrayInitialize(EmaTrendBuffer, 0);
      ArrayInitialize(EmaShortBuffer, 0);
      ArrayInitialize(TrendBuffer, 0);
     }
   else
      limit++;

//--- main loop
   for(int i = limit-1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
      if(i >= MathMin(shift-1, rates_total-1-50))
         continue; //omit some old rates to prevent "Array out of range" or slow calculation

      //Indicator Buffer 1
      double myEmaTrend             = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaTrend_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i);
      EmaTrendBuffer[i] = myEmaTrend;
      double myEmaTrend_Prev        = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaTrend_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);

      double myEmaShort             = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaShort_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i);
      EmaShortBuffer[i] = myEmaShort;
      double myEmaShort_Prev        = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaShort_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);

      double myMACD_Signal          = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,i);
      double myMACD_Signal_Prev     = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,i+1);


      double myMACD                 = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,i);
      double myMACD_Prev            = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,i+1);

      double   myRSI                = iRSI(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myRSI_Period,PRICE_CLOSE,i);
      double   myRSI_Prev           = iRSI(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myRSI_Period,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);

      double   myDeMarker           =iDeMarker(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myDeMarker_Period,i);
      double   myDeMarker_Prev      =iDeMarker(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myDeMarker_Period,i+1);

      bool     BuyTrend = myEmaShort>myEmaTrend;
      bool     BuyTrend_Prev = myEmaShort_Prev>myEmaTrend_Prev;

      //----------
      bool     BuySignal           = BuyTrend && BuyTrend_Prev && myMACD_Prev<myMACD_Signal_Prev && myMACD>myMACD_Signal && myMACD_Prev<0 && myMACD<0;
      bool     BuySignalOut        = (myEma_Bool && BuyTrend_Prev && !BuyTrend) ||
                                     (myRSI_Bool && myRSI>myRSI_High && myRSI_Prev<myRSI_High) ||
                                     (myDeMarker_Bool && myDeMarker>myDeMarker_High && myDeMarker_Prev<myDeMarker_High);
      //----------
      bool     SellSignal          = !BuyTrend && !BuyTrend_Prev && myMACD_Prev>myMACD_Signal_Prev && myMACD<myMACD_Signal && myMACD_Prev>0 && myMACD>0;
      bool     SellSignalOut       = (myEma_Bool && !BuyTrend_Prev && BuyTrend) ||
                                     (myRSI_Bool && myRSI<myRSI_Low && myRSI_Prev>myRSI_Low) ||
                                     (myDeMarker_Bool && myDeMarker<myDeMarker_Low && myDeMarker_Prev>myDeMarker_Low);

      //----------
      ObjectSetString(NULL,"TestPos1",OBJPROP_TEXT,"Profit = "+string(calculatePip(profit)));
      //----------

      if(BuySignal && !BuyOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];

         SetVlineObject("BuySignal"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrGreen);
         SetSquareObject("BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount), Time[i], SquareStartPrice,Time[i], SquareEndPrice,clrGreen);

         objcount++;
         BuySquareCount++;

         BuyOrder_Bool = true;
         SellOrder_Bool = false;
         BuySignalOut_Bool = false;
        }
      if(BuySignalOut && !BuySignalOut_Bool)
        {
         SetVlineObject("BuySignalOut"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrDarkGreen);
         ObjectSet("BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount-1),OBJPROP_TIME2,Time[i]);
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         ObjectSet("BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount-1),OBJPROP_PRICE2,SquareEndPrice);
         ObjectSetString(NULL,"BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount-1)+"text",OBJPROP_TEXT,string(calculatePip(SquareEndPrice-SquareStartPrice)));
         BuyProfit += (SquareEndPrice-SquareStartPrice);
         //profit = (profit+BuyProfit);




         objcount++;
         BuyOrder_Bool = false;
         BuySignalOut_Bool=true;
         //----------
        }


      if(SellSignal && !SellOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];

         SetVlineObject("SellSignal"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrRed);
         SetSquareObject("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount), Time[i], SquareStartPrice,Time[i], SquareEndPrice,clrRed);

         objcount++;
         SellSquareCount++;

         BuyOrder_Bool = false;
         SellOrder_Bool = true;
         SellSignalOut_Bool = false;
        }
      if(SellSignalOut && ! SellSignalOut_Bool)
        {
         SetVlineObject("SellSignalOut"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrDarkRed);
         ObjectSet("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-1),OBJPROP_TIME2,Time[i]);
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         ObjectSet("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-1),OBJPROP_PRICE2,SquareEndPrice);
         ObjectSetString(NULL,"SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-1)+"text",OBJPROP_TEXT,string(calculatePip(SquareStartPrice-SquareEndPrice)));
         SellProfit += (SquareStartPrice-SquareEndPrice);
         profit = (profit+SellProfit);


         objcount++;
         SellOrder_Bool = false;
         SellSignalOut_Bool = true;
        }

     }
   return(rates_total);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| ChartEvent function                                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnChartEvent(const int id,
                  const long &lparam,
                  const double &dparam,
                  const string &sparam)
  {
//---

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetVlineObject                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetVlineObject(string name, datetime t, color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_VLINE,0,t,0);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_COLOR, colour);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_BACK, false);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 4);
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetSquareObject                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetSquareObject(string name, datetime t1, double P1,datetime t2, double P2,color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_RECTANGLE,0,t1,P1,t2,P2);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_CORNER, 1);    // Reference corner
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,colour);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_COLOR,colour);

      ObjectCreate(name+"text",OBJ_TEXT,0,t1,P1);
      ObjectSet(name+"text",OBJPROP_COLOR,SquareTextColor);
      ObjectSet(name+"text",OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,25);
      ObjectSet(name+"text", OBJPROP_ANCHOR,4);
     }
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetLabelObject                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetLabelObject(string name, string text, double P1, double P2,color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
      ObjectSetString(NULL,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_CORNER, 1);    // Reference corner
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, P1);// X coordinate
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, P2);// Y coordinate
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,colour);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_COLOR,colour);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,25);
     }
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetButtonObject                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetButtonObject(string name,string text, double P1, double P2,color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_BUTTON,0,0,0,0);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_CORNER, 1);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,P1);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,P2);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_XSIZE,ButtonXSize);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_YSIZE,40);
      ObjectSetString(NULL,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clrWhite);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,colour);

     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double calculatePip(double number)
  {
   double a = Point;
   number = NormalizeDouble( (number/a) * (pipsmultiplier),Digits);
   number = number * Static_LotSize;
   return(number);
  }




//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
  {
//----
   deleteObjects();
//----
   return(0);
  }


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   Delete CreateObjects                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deleteObjects()
  {
   ObjectsDeleteAll(NULL, OBJ_VLINE); // delete all horizontal lines from the 2nd subwindow
   ObjectsDeleteAll(NULL, OBJ_RECTANGLE);
   ObjectsDeleteAll();
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I needed to do was to add a "BuyOrder_Bool" in the Buy/SellSignalOut and that works now.

```
 if(BuySignal && !BuyOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];

         BuyOrder_Bool = true;
         SellOrder_Bool = false;
         BuySignalOut_Bool = false;
        }
      if(BuySignalOut && !BuySignalOut_Bool && BuyOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         BuyProfit += (SquareEndPrice-SquareStartPrice);
         profit = (profit+BuyProfit);

         objcount++;
         BuyOrder_Bool = false;
         BuySignalOut_Bool=true;
         //----------
        }


      if(SellSignal && !SellOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];

         objcount++;
         SellSquareCount++;

         BuyOrder_Bool = false;
         SellOrder_Bool = true;
         SellSignalOut_Bool = false;
        }
      if(SellSignalOut && ! SellSignalOut_Bool && SellOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         ObjectSet("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-
         SellProfit += (SquareStartPrice-SquareEndPrice);
         profit = (profit+SellProfit);


         objcount++;
         SellOrder_Bool = false;
         SellSignalOut_Bool = true;
        }

     }
```

---

And here is the whole code:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         Test.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
//#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 3
#property indicator_plots   3
//--- plot EmaTrend
#property indicator_label1  "EmaTrend"
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1  clrBlack
#property indicator_style1  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width1  4
//--- plot EmaShort
#property indicator_label2  "EmaShort"
#property indicator_type2   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color2  clrRed
#property indicator_style2  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width2  4
//--- plot Trend
#property indicator_label3  "Trend"
#property indicator_type3   DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color3  clrGreen
#property indicator_style3  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width3  4
//--- input parameters
//input int            LookBack= 5000;
input datetime       LookBackTo = D'2020.05.01 00:00:00';
extern double        Static_LotSize=0.01;

extern string        ____Moving_Average____ = " //////////////////// ";
input int            myEmaTrend_Value       = 350;
input int            myEmaShort_Value       = 9;

extern string        ____MACD____ = " //////////////////// ";
//input bool            myMACD_Bool            = true;
input int            myMACD_FAST_EMA        =12;
input int            myMACD_SLOW_EMA        =26;
input int            myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA      =9;

extern string        ____RSI____ = " //////////////////// ";
input int            myRSI_Period           =14;
input int            myRSI_High             =70;
input int            myRSI_Low              =30;

extern string        ____DeMarker____ = " //////////////////// ";
input int            myDeMarker_Period      =14;
input double         myDeMarker_High        =0.70;
input double         myDeMarker_Low         =0.30;

extern string        ____BuySellSignalOut____= " //////////////////// ";
input bool           myEma_Bool             = true;
input bool           myRSI_Bool             = false;
input bool           myDeMarker_Bool        = false;

extern string        ____OtherSettings____= " //////////////////// ";
input bool           Vline_Bool             = false;




bool                 BuyOrder_Bool           = false;
bool                 SellOrder_Bool          = false;
bool                 BuySignalOut_Bool       = false;
bool                 SellSignalOut_Bool      = false;

double               SquareStartPrice        = 0;
double               SquareEndPrice          = 0;
double               OrderStartPrice         = 0;
double               BuyProfit               = 0;
double               SellProfit              = 0;
double               profit                  = 0;

int                  objcount=0;
int                  BuySquareCount=0;
int                  SellSquareCount=0;

color                SquareTextColor=clrBlack;
color                InfoTextColor=clrBlack;
int                  ButtonXSize      = 140;
double               pipsmultiplier;

//--- indicator buffers
double         EmaTrendBuffer[];
double         EmaShortBuffer[];
double         TrendBuffer[];
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//--- indicator buffers mapping
   SetIndexBuffer(0,EmaTrendBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,EmaShortBuffer);
   SetIndexBuffer(2,TrendBuffer);
   deleteObjects();

   if(MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_DIGITS)==3 && MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_DIGITS)==5)
     {
      pipsmultiplier=10;
     }
   else
     {
      pipsmultiplier=1;
     }

//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {
//--- initial zero
   int limit = rates_total - prev_calculated;
   ArraySetAsSeries(EmaTrendBuffer, true);
   ArraySetAsSeries(EmaShortBuffer, true);
   ArraySetAsSeries(TrendBuffer, true);
   SetLabelObject("TestPos1","TestPos1",10,40,InfoTextColor);


   int      shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,LookBackTo);                 
   Comment("BuyProfit = "+string(calculatePip(BuyProfit))+ "\n" 
            +"SellProfit = "+string(calculatePip(SellProfit))+ "\n" 
            +"SHIFT = "+string(shift)+ "\n" 
            //+"Vline_Bool = "+Vline_Bool
            );

   if(prev_calculated < 1)
     {
      ArrayInitialize(EmaTrendBuffer, 0);
      ArrayInitialize(EmaShortBuffer, 0);
      ArrayInitialize(TrendBuffer, 0);
     }
   else
      limit++;

//--- main loop
   for(int i = limit-1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
      if(i >= MathMin(shift-1, rates_total-1-50))
         continue; //omit some old rates to prevent "Array out of range" or slow calculation

      //Indicator Buffer 1
      double myEmaTrend             = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaTrend_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i);
      EmaTrendBuffer[i] = myEmaTrend;
      double myEmaTrend_Prev        = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaTrend_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);

      double myEmaShort             = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaShort_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i);
      EmaShortBuffer[i] = myEmaShort;
      double myEmaShort_Prev        = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myEmaShort_Value,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);

      double myMACD_Signal          = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,i);
      double myMACD_Signal_Prev     = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,i+1);


      double myMACD                 = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,i);
      double myMACD_Prev            = iMACD(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myMACD_FAST_EMA,myMACD_SLOW_EMA,myMACD_SIGNAL_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,i+1);

      double   myRSI                = iRSI(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myRSI_Period,PRICE_CLOSE,i);
      double   myRSI_Prev           = iRSI(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myRSI_Period,PRICE_CLOSE,i+1);

      double   myDeMarker           =iDeMarker(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myDeMarker_Period,i);
      double   myDeMarker_Prev      =iDeMarker(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,myDeMarker_Period,i+1);

      bool     BuyTrend = myEmaShort>myEmaTrend;
      bool     BuyTrend_Prev = myEmaShort_Prev>myEmaTrend_Prev;

      //----------
      bool     BuySignal           = BuyTrend && BuyTrend_Prev && myMACD_Prev<myMACD_Signal_Prev && myMACD>myMACD_Signal && myMACD_Prev<0 && myMACD<0;
      bool     BuySignalOut        = (myEma_Bool && BuyTrend_Prev && !BuyTrend) ||
                                     (myRSI_Bool && myRSI>myRSI_High && myRSI_Prev<myRSI_High) ||
                                     (myDeMarker_Bool && myDeMarker>myDeMarker_High && myDeMarker_Prev<myDeMarker_High);
      //----------
      bool     SellSignal          = !BuyTrend && !BuyTrend_Prev && myMACD_Prev>myMACD_Signal_Prev && myMACD<myMACD_Signal && myMACD_Prev>0 && myMACD>0;
      bool     SellSignalOut       = (myEma_Bool && !BuyTrend_Prev && BuyTrend) ||
                                     (myRSI_Bool && myRSI<myRSI_Low && myRSI_Prev>myRSI_Low) ||
                                     (myDeMarker_Bool && myDeMarker<myDeMarker_Low && myDeMarker_Prev>myDeMarker_Low);

      //----------
      ObjectSetString(NULL,"TestPos1",OBJPROP_TEXT,"Profit = "+string(calculatePip(profit)));
      //----------

      if(BuySignal && !BuyOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];

         SetVlineObject("BuySignal"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrGreen);
         SetSquareObject("BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount), Time[i], SquareStartPrice,Time[i], SquareEndPrice,clrGreen);

         objcount++;
         BuySquareCount++;

         BuyOrder_Bool = true;
         SellOrder_Bool = false;
         BuySignalOut_Bool = false;
        }
      if(BuySignalOut && !BuySignalOut_Bool && BuyOrder_Bool)
        {
         SetVlineObject("BuySignalOut"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrDarkGreen);
         ObjectSet("BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount-1),OBJPROP_TIME2,Time[i]);
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         ObjectSet("BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount-1),OBJPROP_PRICE2,SquareEndPrice);
         ObjectSetString(NULL,"BuySquare"+string(BuySquareCount-1)+"text",OBJPROP_TEXT,string(calculatePip(SquareEndPrice-SquareStartPrice)));
         BuyProfit += (SquareEndPrice-SquareStartPrice);
         profit = (profit+BuyProfit);




         objcount++;
         BuyOrder_Bool = false;
         BuySignalOut_Bool=true;
         //----------
        }


      if(SellSignal && !SellOrder_Bool)
        {
         SquareStartPrice   = Close[i];
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];

         SetVlineObject("SellSignal"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrRed);
         SetSquareObject("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount), Time[i], SquareStartPrice,Time[i], SquareEndPrice,clrRed);

         objcount++;
         SellSquareCount++;

         BuyOrder_Bool = false;
         SellOrder_Bool = true;
         SellSignalOut_Bool = false;
        }
      if(SellSignalOut && ! SellSignalOut_Bool && SellOrder_Bool)
        {
         SetVlineObject("SellSignalOut"+string(objcount), Time[i], clrDarkRed);
         ObjectSet("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-1),OBJPROP_TIME2,Time[i]);
         SquareEndPrice = Close[i];
         ObjectSet("SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-1),OBJPROP_PRICE2,SquareEndPrice);
         ObjectSetString(NULL,"SellSquare"+string(SellSquareCount-1)+"text",OBJPROP_TEXT,string(calculatePip(SquareStartPrice-SquareEndPrice)));
         SellProfit += (SquareStartPrice-SquareEndPrice);
         profit = (profit+SellProfit);


         objcount++;
         SellOrder_Bool = false;
         SellSignalOut_Bool = true;
        }

     }
   return(rates_total);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| ChartEvent function                                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnChartEvent(const int id,
                  const long &lparam,
                  const double &dparam,
                  const string &sparam)
  {
//---

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetVlineObject                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetVlineObject(string name, datetime t, color colour)
  {
   if(Vline_Bool && ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_VLINE,0,t,0);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_COLOR, colour);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_BACK, false);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 4);
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetSquareObject                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetSquareObject(string name, datetime t1, double P1,datetime t2, double P2,color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_RECTANGLE,0,t1,P1,t2,P2);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_CORNER, 1);    // Reference corner
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,colour);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_COLOR,colour);

      ObjectCreate(name+"text",OBJ_TEXT,0,t1,P1);
      ObjectSet(name+"text",OBJPROP_COLOR,SquareTextColor);
      ObjectSet(name+"text",OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,25);
      ObjectSet(name+"text", OBJPROP_ANCHOR,4);
     }
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetLabelObject                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetLabelObject(string name, string text, double P1, double P2,color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
      ObjectSetString(NULL,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_CORNER, 1);    // Reference corner
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, P1);// X coordinate
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, P2);// Y coordinate
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,colour);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_COLOR,colour);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,25);
     }
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| SetButtonObject                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void SetButtonObject(string name,string text, double P1, double P2,color colour)
  {
   if(ObjectFind(name) == -1)
     {
      ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_BUTTON,0,0,0,0);
      ObjectSet(name, OBJPROP_CORNER, 1);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,P1);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,P2);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_XSIZE,ButtonXSize);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_YSIZE,40);
      ObjectSetString(NULL,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clrWhite);
      ObjectSet(name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,colour);

     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double calculatePip(double number)
  {
   double a = Point;
   number = NormalizeDouble( (number/a) * (pipsmultiplier),Digits);
   number = number * Static_LotSize;
   return(number);
  }




//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
  {
//----
   deleteObjects();
//----
   return(0);
  }


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|   Delete CreateObjects                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deleteObjects()
  {
   ObjectsDeleteAll(NULL, OBJ_VLINE); // delete all horizontal lines from the 2nd subwindow
   ObjectsDeleteAll(NULL, OBJ_RECTANGLE);
   ObjectsDeleteAll();
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```